# Concatenate int and string as constant - Golang

Tags: go, concatenation

I am searching for a way to concatenate constant string and constant integer in Golang and save the result as **constant** as well.
My goal is to concatenate math.MaxInt32 to a string like this :

```
const reportMsg = "the maximum int value is " + math.MaxInt32
```

I have tried the following :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

const (
    reportMsg = "the maximum int value is " + string(math.MaxInt32)
    //some other unrelated consts here
)

func main(){
    fmt.Println(reportMsg)
}
```

which resulted in the following error:

```
conversion from untyped int to string yields a string of one rune, not a string of digits (did you mean fmt.Sprint(x)?)
```

I have also tried to replace `string(math.MaxInt32)` with `fmt.Sprint(math.MaxInt32)`, but got another error :

```
"the maximum int value is " + fmt.Sprint(math.MaxInt32) is not a constant
```

And the same with `strconv.Itoi(math.MaxInt32)`

And from my search, I understood that an output from a function is not considered a constant.
So is there any way at all to concatenate constant string & constant int while STILL store the result in constant?

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to do and make it a constant. Why not make it a variable?

Comment: @AndySchweig
because there are many other constants that uses reportMsg as a base

Comment: then define an getter function parameterising the things you want to add after the constant.

Comment: @DiptoMondal can you explain more or give an example ?

Comment: @DiptoMondal IIUC that will still be a function, in most of the cases calling a function as a constant is not constant  , unless I am mistaken

Comment: Yes you are right. As you have said that reportMsg is being used as base in many where and you can't append a function's result to a constant so I was just trying to make things maintainable by using getter function which will return your desired output appending the parameter you have passed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it a constant, you would need to precalculate the value:

```
package main

const (
   maxInt32 = "2147483647"
   reportMsg = "the maximum int value is " + maxInt32
)

func main() {
   println(reportMsg)
}
```

Comment: I was in this place at first but wanted to improve it to use the constant math.maxInt32